# StompJs only works in debugging mode - React Native

Tags: react-native, websocket, stompjs

```
import * as Stomp from "stompjs";
import _ from "lodash";
export const MESSAGE_TYPE_CHAT_TYPING = "ChatTyping";
export const MESSAGE_TYPE_CHAT_MESSAGE = "ChatMessage";
export const RECONNECT_DELAY = 3000;

export function wsConnect(user, callback, ondisconnected) {

 const webSocket = Stomp.client(url);
 webSocket.debug = () => {};
 webSocket.connect({},() => {
   callback ? callback(webSocket) : _.noop();
  },
  error => {
    // console.log(error);
    console.log("Connection lost...");
    if (ondisconnected) {
      ondisconnected();
     }
   }
  );

  return webSocket;
 }
```

The connection between the StompJs over WebSocket is established only when the app is in debugging mode.

Comment: Did you solve this? I found a similar issue

Comment: I couldn't. I had to build replace stompjs with socket.io.

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across the same problem and fixed it by installing `text-encoding` package and enabling `forceBinaryWSFrames` and `appendMissingNULLonIncoming` properties

- `npm install text-encoding --save`
- Add `import * as encoding from 'text-encoding';` to App.js

```
const client = Stomp.over(socket);
client. Connect({
    forceBinaryWSFrames:true,
    appendMissingNULLonIncoming:true
}, (frame) => {
    console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
});
```